# Generating dynamic sub domains

Tags: dynamic, subdomain

I am willing to generate dynamic subdomains so that I can provide my clients personalised url but it should open the same(dynamic) page for all URL.

```
    e.g. www.max.juniferpharma.in
```

I have generated it with some .htaccess tips but its seems not working.

My url: http://juniferpharma.in/

I have added A records:

```
Host - * Points to - my ip address TTL - 7200
```

my .htaccess files looks something like this:

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.juniferpharma.in
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://juniferpharma.in/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^juniferpharma\.in$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yourwebsite_folder/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule (.*) /yourwebsite_folder/$1

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.yourwebsite.com
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yourwebsite_folder/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule (.*) /yourwebsite_folder/$1
```

Please help me in this issue. Looking forward.

Comment: You are not detailing your issue enough. Please see [mcve].